# How to install newest PHP on kali linux?

Tags: php, kali-linux

I try to upgrade from PHP 5.6.23 to the newest PHP version.
How can I do this?

I found the newest PHP versions [here](http://php.net/get/php-7.1.2.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror).

But there are no install instructions.

Comment: You probably shouldn't. Kali's meant as a platform for specific tools rather than a general purpose OS. If you need a modern version of PHP, use a proper distro like ubuntu. Ironically, many of the choices made with kali make it somewhat insecure, and you don't know if upgrading PHP will break anything else.

Comment: @Aibobot, my whole company uses kali linux and this should not be a problem at all.

Comment: @EdwardBlack If your whole company uses Kali, your company may want to look into their own security....

Comment: we are security company

Answer (score -1):

Open the terminal and type in as root:

```
apt-get install php*
```

Then you should be able to use the newest version of php

Comment: Old answer, but using the apt packages doesn’t always mean you are getting the latest version of PHP as far as the larger world goes. Each distro for anything only has one or maybe two versions of PHP that have been back patched to be secure with modern advisories but are still older versions of PHP.